# Scheme: How to test if an object is a lambda expression

Tags: lambda, scheme

How do you test if an object in scheme is a lambda expression? Something that looks like this:

```
(define call-if-can (lambda (x)
    (if (function? x)
        (x)
        x)))
```

Thank you!

Comment: maybe `procedure?` http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_sec_6.4 is the closest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [`procedure?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._procedure~3f%29%29) predicate, which is standard Scheme:

```
(define (call-if-can x)
  (if (procedure? x)
      (x)
      x))
```

It works as expected:

```
(define (test) (+ 1 1))

(call-if-can 1)
=> 1
(call-if-can test)
=> 2
```

Comment: "Try using the *procedure* `procedure?`" would be more scheme lingo. I have yet to see literature about Scheme that writes about functions.

Comment: @Sylwester I tried to avoid the repetition :P . In fact, a _predicate_ would be a more precise word in this context.